# Import txt file and having each line as a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, file-io

I'm a new Python user.

I have a txt file that will be something like:

```
3,1,3,2,3
3,2,2,3,2
2,1,3,3,2,2
1,2,2,3,3,1
3,2,1,2,2,3
```

but may be less or more lines.

I want to import each line as a list.

I know you can do it as such:

```
filename = 'MyFile.txt' 
fin=open(filename,'r')
L1list = fin.readline()
L2list = fin.readline()
L3list = fin.readline()
```

but since I don't know how many lines I will have, is there another way to create individual lists?

Answer (score 26):

Do not create separate lists; create a list of lists:

```
results = []
with open('inputfile.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        results.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

or better still, use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

results = []
with open('inputfile.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        results.append(row)
```

Lists or dictionaries are *far* superiour structures to keep track of an arbitrary number of things read from a file.

Note that either loop also lets you address the rows of data individually without having to read all the contents of the file into memory either; instead of using `results.append()` just process that line right there.

Just for completeness sake, here's the one-liner compact version to read in a CSV file into a list in one go:

```
import csv

with open('inputfile.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
    results = list(csv.reader(inputfile))
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a list of lists:

```
with open("/path/to/file") as file:
    lines = []
    for line in file:
        # The rstrip method gets rid of the "\n" at the end of each line
        lines.append(line.rstrip().split(","))
```

Comment: Hi iCodez- I'm actually trying to use this and while it is making a list of lists, the list actually only has one item within it- the input file that I'm using right now (as referenced in the original question) has three lines, so there should be three lists. Using your approach I'm just getting [['3', '2', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1\r1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '1', '1', '2', '2', '1', '3']]. Any thoughts? Thanks so much.

Comment: @John - I can't reproduce your problem.  I tested my code on the 5 line example you gave and it worked just as it should have.  It made a list of 5 lists, one for each line.  Are you sure the file has 3 lines and not just one long line?

Comment: @John - Also, I would look at the comment on Pieters answer explaining the `open` built-in.  Maybe that can fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks iCodez- it was indeed an issue on my end. I had two versions of the test .txt file I had been working with, and had been pointing to the wrong one....thanks for your patience and assistance!

Comment: @John - More than happy to help!  Don't forget to accept an answer though (click the tick) to help keep SO clean and organized (all questions without an accepted answer remain in the "unanswered" bin).

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile: # try open('...', 'rb') as well
    answer = [line.strip().split(',') for line in infile]
```

If you want the numbers as `int`s:

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = [[int(i) for i in line.strip().split(',')] for line in infile]
```

Comment: Thanks! One follow up question-0 I'm getting the error                   File "seventeen_v2.3.py", line 7, in <module>
    answer = [[int(i) for i in line.strip().split(',')] for line in infile]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1\r1'
The txt file only has digits in it- any idea why python is adding this "\r1" to the input?

Answer (score -1):

```
lines=[]
with open('file') as file:
   lines.append(file.readline())
```

Comment: You will need to give a more complete answer.  As it currently stands, this doesn't do what the OP wants.